# How to read FTP log

Tags: logging, download, upload, ftp

If I look at the FTP access log from Apache, how do I know which files are uploaded or downloaded?

For example: here are two typical lines:

```
Mon May 18 10:09:57 2015 1 166.166.30.166 168166 /home/user/public_html/files/screenshot-2.png b _ o r user ftp 1 * c
Mon May 18 10:09:59 2015 0 166.166.30.166 45 /home/user/public_html/files/sitemap.php a _ o r user ftp 1 * c
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the [xferlog(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/xferlog) format.  To determine whether a file has been uploaded or downloaded, you would look at the `direction` field, which has values "i" (incoming, meaning *uploaded*), or "o" (outgoing, meaning *downloaded*).